# How can I make Set-Cookie warning disappear on MERN app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, cross-site, samesite

so I have an app made with the MERN stack, and I set up the next code on my server.js

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict");
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

But I keep seeing on chrome the warning "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://fontawesome.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute."

Some of my CSS is not working after build, so I don't know if that could be the affecting in some ways.

Comment: I found the issue with the CSS, so this is not definitely an issue, but still would like to know how can I fix the issue of the warning. Thanks. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie is associated with the `fontawesome.com` domain which means they are responsible for updating this attribute. The team there is aware of this issue and has updated their code. You can take a look at [this issue on their GitHub](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/15643) for more context.